# Webscraping - Iterate through a table row with active/inactive status

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to web-scrape the information on:
https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/date/2019-01-13/sport/4/slate/5c3c66edb1699a43c0d7bba7/contest/5c3c66f2b1699a43c0d7bd0d

There is a main table with a column `user`. When you click on a `user`, there is another table beside that shows the information of the team of that user enters in the contest. I want to extract the team of all the users. Therefore, I need to be able to go through all the users by **clicking** on them and then extracting the information on the second table. Here is my code to extract the team of the first user:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromedriver =("C:/Users/Michel/Desktop/python/package/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
DFSteam = []

driver.get("https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/date/2019-01- 13/sport/4/slate/5c3c66edb1699a43c0d7bba7/contest/5c3c66f2b1699a43c0d7bd0d")
Team1=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.ant-table-fixed")
driver.close
print(Team1.text)
```

However, I am not able to iterate through the different users. I noticed that when I click on a `user` the tr class of that row switch for inactive to active in the page source code, but I do not know how to use that. Moreover, I would like to store the team extracted in a data frame. I am not sure if it is better to do it at the same time or afterwards.
The data frame would look like this:

> RANK(team) / C / C / W / W / W / D / D /G/ UTIL/ TOTAL($) / Total Points
> 1        / Mark Scheifel/ Mickael Backlund/ Artemi Panarin / Nick Foligno / Michael Frolik / Mark Giordano / Zach Werenski / CConnor Hellebuyck / Brandon Tanev / 50 000 / 54.60

Comment: can you be a little clearer on how you'd you expect the output? I have all the lineups of each user, but not sure how you want it stored. I could just store it as a json? or a dataframe is fine too, but how do you want it to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. It's just a matter of finding the username element to click on then grab the lineup table, reformat to combine into one results dataframe.

[image]

The user name text is tagged with `<a>`. Just need to find the `<a>` tag that matched the user name.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/date/2019-01-13/sport/4/slate/5c3c66edb1699a43c0d7bba7/contest/5c3c66f2b1699a43c0d7bd0d'

# Open Browser and go to site
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)


# Waits until tables are loaded and has text. Timeouts after 60 seconds
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/tbody//tr//td//span//a[text() != ""]')))

# Get tables to get the user names
tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
users_df  = tables[0][['Rank','User']]
users_df['User'] = users_df['User'].str.replace(' Member', '')

# Initialize results dataframe and iterate through users
results = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in users_df.iterrows():

    rank = row['Rank']
    user = row['User']

    # Find the user name and click on the name
    user_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='%s']" %(user))[0]
    user_link.click()

    # Get the lineup table after clicking on the user name
    tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
    lineup = tables[1]

    #print (user)
    #print (lineup)

    # Restructure to put into resutls dataframe
    lineup.loc[9, 'Name'] = lineup.iloc[9]['Salary']
    lineup.loc[10, 'Name'] = lineup.iloc[9]['Pts']

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(lineup['Name'].values.reshape(-1, 11), 
                    columns=lineup['Pos'].iloc[:9].tolist() + ['Total_$', 'Total_Pts'] )

    temp_df.insert(loc=0, column = 'User', value = user)
    temp_df.insert(loc=0, column = 'Rank', value = rank)

    results = results.append(temp_df)

results = results.reset_index(drop=True)

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
    Rank            User    ...        Total_$ Total_Pts
0      1    Canadaman101    ...     $50,000.00      54.6
1      2  MayhemLikeMe27    ...     $50,000.00      53.9
2      2    gunslinger58    ...     $50,000.00      53.9
3      4        oilkings    ...     $48,600.00      53.6
4      5           TTB19    ...     $50,000.00      53.4
5      6      Adamjloder    ...     $49,800.00      53.1
6      7     DollarBillW    ...     $49,900.00      52.6
7      8     Biglarry696    ...     $49,900.00      52.4
8      8       tical1994    ...     $49,900.00      52.4
9      8        rollem02    ...     $49,900.00      52.4
10     8         kchoban    ...     $50,000.00      52.4
11     8       TBirdSCIL    ...     $49,900.00      52.4
12    13        manny716    ...     $49,900.00      52.1
13    14        JayKooks    ...     $50,000.00      51.9
14    15        Cambie19    ...     $49,900.00      51.4
15    16         mjh6588    ...     $50,000.00      51.1
16    16    shanefriesen    ...     $50,000.00      51.1
17    16        mnfish42    ...     $50,000.00      51.1
18    19        Pugsly55    ...     $49,900.00      50.9
19    19         volpez7    ...     $50,000.00      50.9
20    19        Scherr47    ...     $49,900.00      50.9
21    19    Testosterown    ...     $50,000.00      50.9
22    23         markm22    ...     $49,700.00      50.6
23    23  foreveryoung12    ...     $49,800.00      50.6
24    23       STP_Picks    ...     $49,900.00      50.6
25    26    jibbinghippo    ...     $49,800.00      50.4
26    26     loumister35    ...     $49,900.00      50.4
27    26         creels3    ...     $50,000.00      50.4
28    26        JayKooks    ...     $50,000.00      51.9
29    26   mmeiselman731    ...     $49,900.00      50.4
30    26         volpez7    ...     $50,000.00      50.9
31    26   tommienation1    ...     $49,900.00      50.4
32    26    jibbinghippo    ...     $49,800.00      50.4
33    26    Testosterown    ...     $50,000.00      50.9
34    35           nut07    ...     $50,000.00      49.9
35    35         volpez7    ...     $50,000.00      50.9
36    35        durfdurf    ...     $50,000.00      49.9
37    35    chupacabra21    ...     $50,000.00      49.9
38    39       Mbermes01    ...     $50,000.00      49.6
39    40        suerte41    ...     $50,000.00      49.4
40    40   spliksskins77    ...     $50,000.00      49.4
41    42     Andrewskoff    ...     $49,600.00      49.1
42    42          Alky14    ...     $49,800.00      49.1
43    42         bretned    ...     $50,000.00      49.1
44    42         bretned    ...     $50,000.00      49.1
45    42        gehrig38    ...     $49,700.00      49.1
46    42      d-train_91    ...     $49,500.00      49.1
47    42   DiamondDallas    ...     $50,000.00      49.1
48    49           jdmre    ...     $50,000.00      48.9
49    49         Devosty    ...     $50,000.00      48.9

[50 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: How do you find the XPATH of users in: `user_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='%s']" %(user))[0]` ? And how it is woking the %(user) you add ? Thanks

Comment: once the page loaded, I did Inspect and saw that right after the `<span>` tag is `<a>` that, which is where the user text is. So I just needed to find the `<a>` tag that had the text `Canadaman101'. then do `.click()`. Then get the lineup table. Find the `<a>` tag that had text of `MayhemLikeMe27`. then do `.click()`. Then get the lineup table, etc, etc, etc

Comment: the %(user) is just the variable. It finds `%s` and replaces it with the string user. I could have also done: `user_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[text()=" + user + "]")[0]

Comment: selenium is tricky. I still don't have it exactly down, and not as straightforward to me as say BeautifulSoup. lots of testing and playing around for me while I'm learning exactly all the selenium ways to do stuff. but it's fun

Comment: What if I want to go through all the pages? I need to click on the _next button_ at the bottom and then create a **for loop**. However, you can click on the button as long as you want; even if there are no more entries. I try to add:  `pages=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button")
for p in pages:
    p.click()` But it is clicking on the wrong button. I also try:`pages=driver.find_element_by_class_name("ant-btn ant-btn-icon-only")`

Comment: there's a bunch of buttons. so it's clicking the first one it finds. use this for the next page: `next_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")`
   `next_button[2].click()`